# If code behind not used, is aspx source code exposed to website visitors?

Tags: asp.net, web

I've read through some of the questions here and my understanding is that this is true. Could someone confirm that visitors to an ASP.NET website can actually download the aspx files in their original format? Just like with the css files, etc. Thanks.

**Clarification**: Please be patient with me. I am newbie and just want to make sure I understand. I know that using Dreamweaver, a person can just download almost all the source files from a website. At least that what could be done some years ago with many websites. He would just change a few text contents and have a similar website like the original with all the original design, images, etc.

So if he can do the same with an asp.net site: downloading all the files, he can look at the aspx file and see what the code does. I am not talking about him executing the page and do the view source command. This file would naturally be processed by the server and doesn't expose source code.

This is one of the reasons why code behind is recommended because the code can be compiled and the source is not uploaded to the site. Only the dll is uploaded and minimum logic is exposed through the aspx file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in newbie's term:
No, the server won't give you ASPX and code behind files, these are files that don't mean anything to the end-user/visitor/browsers. These codes are processed on the server, and what you get is only a bunch of HTML code, javascripts, css, images, etc. which browsers can render.

If you try to "download" (by accessing them through your browser) .ASPX, .CS, and WEB.CONFIG files to see the actual source code, well you simply can't.

Answer (score 4):

**No, they can't**. The ASPX page contains server-side code that is executed, well, by the server, and ends up containing plain HTML that the client browser can understand.

When IIS receives a GET request for an ASPX page, the ASP.NET handler kicks in and returns the processed HTML. So unless IIS is misconfigured, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

No. Visitors cannot see your business logic.

If that were the case the markup `asp:TextBox` wont get rendered as `input type='text'`
Also, if that were the case we would be seeing code snippets of sites written using scripting languages like `PHP` or `Classic ASP`